# Can not connect python to h2o instance (version mismatch)

Tags: python, h2o

I have just run an upgrade on the h2o package in python, but am only getting a version of 3.10.4.1. However, my recently upgraded h2o application is running 3.10.4.6 - can you please help me rectify this discrepancy? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An H2O version mismatch is caused when the H2O Java application and the **h2o**  Python module (or R package) have different version numbers.  If you only use the **h2o** Python module, this will not happen.  However, if you launch an H2O cluster from the command line, `java -jar h2o.jar`, and then connect to it via the **h2o** Python module, the version numbers can be in disagreement.

If this happens, the best way to resolve is to kill the existing Java process and start the H2O cluster from inside the **h2o** Python module.  Alternatively, you can `pip uninstall h2o`, visit the [H2O Downloads page](http://h2o.ai/download) and install the matching version of the Python package.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. It was a path mixup which I have fixed and now can see the same h2o.**version** from the cmd and jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution: Best way is to match both the versions.
Try to be on the latest. Few things are tricky while matching the versions. When you are upgrading the one that has lower version, make sure you do `h2o.shutdown()` to shut the h2o else, the uninstall or install won't happen successfully. 
And then go to [h2o-ai](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable.html) and follow the steps